# on e.keycode == 9 (tab), add 12 spaces, and prevent default behavior

Tags: jquery

Have a slight problem with this code :

```
jQuery.fn.markCursor = function(e){
    $(this).focus();
   $(this).keyup(function(e) {
  $cursorStart.enterText(e);

});

};

jQuery.fn.enterText = function(e){

if (e.keyCode == 9){
    $cursor.val("");
    alert("hello");
}

};
```

The tab key is resorting to its default behavior in the browser, would .preventdefault help here? How would I add 12 spaces without the code taking up 12 lines in jquery :p

Comment: "would .preventdefault help here?" - have you even tried?

Comment: yes I tried but it seems that tab has a clear issue, I was just wondering if anyone else had more clarity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`e.preventDefault()` would help. If you want to add twelfe spaces without literally typing them, use `Array(12).join(" ");`. Surely, typing twelfe spaces may be easier.

Some methods to type twelfe spaces:

```
var s=[];s.length=12;s.join(" ");
var s=Array(12).join(" ");
var s="            "; //Shortest so far.
```

As you can see, using `Array(i).join(" ")` starts being useful when `i` is higher than 17. Note that the this approach enables a dynamic indenting feature.

**EDIT**
Quick tuturial on key events:

- `keydown` - Initiated when the key is pressed **down**. This event is fired **once**, before any default event has occured
- `keypress` - This event is fired (**multiple times**) while the key is pressed down, before a default event has occured.
- `keyup` - Fired after the key has been **released** (which happens only **once** per set of key events). Needless to say, all of the default events have already been occured.

`keydown` and `keypress` can be used to **capture and cancel** key events. If you want to catch and validate all key events, use `keypress`. If you've assigned multiple events (eg to `window` and to `input`), you may also use `e.stopPropagation()` in conjunction with `e.preventDefault()`. The first function stops the event from bubbling further (=the event isn't passed to other event listeners any more). The second function prevents the default behaviour from occuring.

Comment: e.preventDefault() doesn't seem to work for me though, on pressing tab, the cursor just goes to the url

Comment: Editing answer, included a short but complete tuturial about key events.

Answer (score 5):

To catch the tab keypress, you would have to bind to the `keydown` event. When pressing tab, a `keyup` event is not triggered.

Answer (score 1):

I'm so sick of the overuse of Jquery. If you look at the preventDefault function, all it does is change the return value of window.event.

```
function stopTab(e){
    e=e||window.event;
    if(e.keyCode==9){
        document.querySelector('textarea').value+='            ';
        e.returnValue= false;
    }

}
```

You'll have to do something about the appending space problem by finding the cursor's position.

Comment: how would this be used though...would I need to declare this in the markcursor before the keyup to intercept it?